# Why I can't add && to Ret (Args...) &?

Tags: c++, function, types

When I was trying to write my own `decay_t` like this:

```
#include <utility>
template <class T>
struct auto_decay {
    auto operator () () noexcept {
        return std::declval<T>();
    }
};

template <class T> using decay_t = decltype( (decl_as<decay_impl::auto_decay< T >>())() );
```

And test it using:

```
#include <type_traits>
int main() {
    static_assert(is_same<decay_t<int ()&>, int (*)()>{}());
}
```

I got the following errors:

```
In file included from test_decay.cc:1:
In file included from ./../src/decay.hpp:4:
In file included from ./../src/utility.hpp:3:
./../src/add_reference.hpp:17:14: error: reference to function type 'int () &' cannot have '&' qualifier
    typedef T&& type;
             ^
./../src/add_reference.hpp:20:1: note: in instantiation of template class 'nxwheels::concept_check::add_rvalue_reference<int () &>' requested here
using add_rvalue_reference_t = typename add_rvalue_reference<T>::type;
^
./../src/utility.hpp:14:1: note: in instantiation of template type alias 'add_rvalue_reference_t' requested here
auto declval() noexcept -> add_rvalue_reference_t<T>;
^
./../src/decay.hpp:10:16: note: while substituting explicitly-specified template arguments into function template 'declval' 
        return declval<T>();
               ^
./../src/decay.hpp:16:46: note: in instantiation of member function 'nxwheels::concept_check::decay_impl::auto_decay<int () &>::operator()' requested here
template <class T> using decay_t = decltype( (decl_as<decay_impl::auto_decay< T >>())() );
                                             ^
test_decay.cc:17:17: note: in instantiation of template type alias 'decay_t' requested here
    assert_same<decay_t<int (void)&>, int (*)(void)>();
                ^
In file included from test_decay.cc:1:
./../src/decay.hpp:10:16: error: call to function 'declval' that is neither visible in the template definition nor found by argument-dependent lookup
        return declval<T>();
               ^
./../src/decay.hpp:16:46: note: in instantiation of member function 'nxwheels::concept_check::decay_impl::auto_decay<int () &>::operator()' requested here
template <class T> using decay_t = decltype( (decl_as<decay_impl::auto_decay< T >>())() );
                                             ^
test_decay.cc:17:17: note: in instantiation of template type alias 'decay_t' requested here
    assert_same<decay_t<int (void)&>, int (*)(void)>();
                ^
./../src/utility.hpp:14:6: note: 'declval' should be declared prior to the call site
auto declval() noexcept -> add_rvalue_reference_t<T>;
     ^
In file included from test_decay.cc:2:
./../src/concepts/is_same.hpp:18:5: error: static_assert failed
    static_assert(is_same_v<T1, T2>);
    ^             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test_decay.cc:17:5: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'nxwheels::concept_check::assert_same<int, int (*)()>' requested here
    assert_same<decay_t<int (void)&>, int (*)(void)>();
    ^
3 errors generated.
```

Why I can't add `&&` to `Ret (Args...) &`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`int () &` is not what you (seem to) think it is.

It's not a reference to function, but rather a [ref-qualified](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions) function.

If you want a reference to function, you need to use `int (&)()`.

---

> Why I can't add `&&` to `Ret (Args...) &`

It seems that qualified (ref- or cv-qualified) function types can be used only in very specific places:

> #### [[dcl.typedef]/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.typedef#nt:typedef-name)
>
> A function type with a *cv-qualifier-seq* or a *ref-qualifier* (including a type named by typedef-name (`[dcl.typedef]`, `[temp.param]`)) shall
>   appear only as:
>
> -- the function type for a non-static member
>   function,
>
> -- the function type to which a pointer to member refers,
>
> -- the top-level function type of a function typedef declaration or
>   *alias-declaration*,
>
> -- the *type-id* in the default argument of a *type-parameter*, or
>
> -- the *type-id* of a *template-argument* for a *type-parameter* (`[temp.arg.type]`).